# How to show the Bengali data stored in the Mysql database on the web page

Tags: php, mysql, internationalization

I am making a CMS and have to submit Bangla data at this CMS and show the Bangla data, But Bangla data is not seen correctly, But click on the submit button to see Bengali properly. how will this problem be resolved?

***Before clicking submit button:***

[image]

***After clicking submit button:***

[image]

***MY code:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
                $servername = "localhost";
                $username = "root";
                $password = "";
                $db ="bangla";
                $con1 = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
                $db_create = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS bangla CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci";

                if ($con1->query($db_create) === TRUE) {
                    echo "Database 'bangla' created successfully<br>";
                } 
                else {
                      echo "Error creating database: " . $con1->error;
                }
                $con2 = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);
                $table_create = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
                    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                    father VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                    village VARCHAR(30)
                )ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";

                if ($con2->query($table_create) === TRUE) {
                    echo "Table 'user' created successfully<br><br>";
                } 
                else {
                      echo "Error creating database: " . $con2->error;
                }

                if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                    mysqli_query($con2, "SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
                    mysqli_query($con2, "SET SESSION collation collation='utf8_general_ci'");
                    $name = $_POST["name"];
                    $father = $_POST["father"];
                    $village = $_POST["village"];
                    $query = "INSERT INTO user (id, name, father, village) 
                    VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$father', '$village')";
                    $run = mysqli_query($con2, $query);
                    if ($run) {echo "User created successfully. ";} 
                    else {echo "User created fail.";}
                }
            ?>  
            <form  method ="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
                <input type="text" name="father" placeholder="father name">
                <input type="text" name="village" placeholder="village name">
                <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
              </form>
                <?php
                $sql = "SELECT name, father, village FROM user";
                $result = $con2->query($sql);
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo "Name:" . $row["name"]. " <br>Father name: " . $row["father"]."<br>Village name:". $row["village"]."<br><br>";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "0 results";
                }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: in DB wheather the record saved in bengali data.

Comment: Try changing your encoding from utf8_general_ci to utf8_unicode_ci, and see if that works

Comment: mysql's php clients defaults to latin1 encoding when connecting. You need to force the charset with `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");` or with `$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");` directly after connecting to the database.

Comment: Your `INSERT` query is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). You should sanitize it.

Comment: thanks Raymond Nijland

Answer (score 0):

Write in 'head' tag
  like

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
```

Comment: please share page url

Comment: $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the same problem by using

$con->set_charset("utf8");

My config file:

```
    <?php

// Creating a database connection

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "bibahabd_datacollect");
if (!$con) {

    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$con->set_charset("utf8");

// Selecting a database

$db = mysqli_select_db($con, "bibahabd_datacollect");
if (!$db) {
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

?>
```